# Image slideshow with remove dynamic remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm using jssor to make a slideshow with an `<ul>` of `<img>` tags loaded dynamically when the user upload images to the server with an AJAX request.

The thing is when the user want to remove some image. I can do that, but in the slideshow it's appear an empty box where the deleted images was.

How can I update or another option to keep this things of remove images dynamically?

Here is my code of creating the slideshow and to remove some item:

```
var i = 0;

for(; i < data.Paths.length; i++) {
    $('#slides').append($("<div id='div_" + i + "''><img u='images' style='width: 225px; height: 150px;' src='"+data.Paths[i]+"' id='img_" + i + "''></div>"));
}

var options = {
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2
    }
};

jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

$(document).on('click', '#delete_photo', function(){
    //Check the data of this button, because we gonna make the button next or previous load the id of the picture inside
    //console.log(jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex()); //Return current index of the element inside the slider.
    var selected_index = jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex();
    var element = "#div_" + selected_index;
    console.log(element);
    $(element).remove();

    var options = {
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $ChanceToShow: 2
        }
    };

    jssor_slider1 = null;
    jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a slider initialized with 4 slides as follows,

```
<div id="slide1">slide 1 content</div>
<div id="slide2">slide 2 content</div>
<div id="slide3">slide 3 content</div>
<div id="slide4">slide 4 content</div>
```

To re-make the slider, you just need to clear content in each slide, and then append new conent in each slide.

```
//do something
$(#slide1).html("new conent for slide 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

jssor slider runs with certain number of slides.
if a slider is initialized with 5 slides, you can't remove or add any slide.

but it's allowed to change contents of each slide dynamically.

Comment: And what about re-making the slider without the slide I previously remove? I've to re-make the HTML container?